# Sitecore Publishing Service does not show the languages and seeing 404 errors

Tags: publishing-service

After installing the Sitecore Publishing Service 2.0 and the associated module, I'm receiving a number of 404 errors in the browser console and the languages are missing from the publishing dialog.

After opening one of the links in a new browser tab, I see the following:

> {"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://www.company.com/sitecore/api/ssc/publishing/Languages/{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}/All'."}

What should I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Hey Praveen, did you get any solution for this issue, i am also facing similar issue but in my case the Target is also missing

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Turns out that this issue is fairly common. Saw this happen in both SXA and the Publishing Service.

The solution is to clear the **Temporary Asp.Net files from IIS**.

Steps:

1. Stop IIS. This can be performed through the UI by selecting the server name in the tree and on the right panel choosing *Stop*. You can also use the command `iisreset /stop` from an elevated prompt.
2. The website is running in 64-bit mode so you can delete the contents of the path `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files`. You'll probably see a folder named **root** along with some others.
3. Start IIS. Reverse the actions from step 1 by choosing *Start* from the UI or running the command `iisreset /start` from an elevated prompt.
4. Clear browser cache for extra measure!

Alternative to`IISReset.exe`:
This is less aggressive because it stops and starts only the critical IIS services. Read more [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sudeepg/2009/02/15/windows-2008-and-iisreset-exe/).

```
net stop w3svc
net stop IISAdmin
net start IISAdmin
net start w3svc
```

**Tip:** Sometimes you may be able to get away with `iisreset` without the switches if you immediately delete the temp files and no traffic is being served up.

There is a short article [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff625735(v=ws.10).aspx) on how to stop IIS from the UI. You may also explore automated PowerShell scripts to perform this task for you, however it is not likely to happen very often. Do note that once the files are deleted, the website will take some time to recompile everything before it's ready for use.

Comment: Could you please precise me where are those files located ?

Comment: that's great. It works for me. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: If your Sitecore instance runs in a docker container, you can restart your CM container to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, and it was because I turned on the `Debug` mode in `Experience Explorer`, and then I just closed the tab without changing back to `Edit` mode.
After I opened `Experience Explorer` in `Edit` mode, the list of Languages was visible, and Publishing started working fine for me.

Comment: YES! had me stumped for a while this one

Answer (score 0):

We had this same issue as we included an external package from a vendor that interfered with routes.  Although your error looks a little different that what we saw.  We had to do the following:

---

When any third-party dlls are referenced in Sitecore, you must configure your MVC application to not resolve third-party dlls unless required. This configuration varies based on how your application is set up (DI, custom routes table, etc). For OOTB Sitecore configuration, as mentioned in the Sitecore configs, please add the assembly names to the following sections in config.

`<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <api>
          <services>
              <configuration type="Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Configuration.ServicesConfiguration, Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure">
               <excludedAssemblies hint="list:AddExcludedAssembly">
                < !--  Dlls  -->
               </excludedAssemblies>

               </configuration>
          </services>
        </api>
        <mvc>
          <configurationAssemblies type="Sitecore.Mvc.Configuration.ExcludedAssembliesConfiguration, Sitecore.Mvc">
           <excludedAssemblies hint="list">
            < !--  Dlls  -->
           </excludedAssemblies>
          </configurationAssemblies>
        </mvc>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>`

This section defines a list of assembly name matches to filter out any assemblies that are not required by the IAssemmblyResolver. Assembly names that start with a name within the excludedAssemblies will not be returned in the results from  IAssembleResolver.GetAssemblies()

Please note that the above-mentioned configs are OOTB sitecore configurations and may change with new version of sitecore and will not work if you are using a non OOTB DI. Please customize your these settings based on your DI container, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just got resolution for my issue which was quite similar to yours [publishing target missing after installing Sitecore publishing module](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/14336/publishing-target-missing-after-installing-sitecore-publishing-module/14338#14338). you can try clearing temporary asp.net files to make sure nothing is cached.