# Sitecore Publishing Service Dialog Languages Missing

Tags: publishing-service

We have setup the Publishing service version 1.1.0 on Sitecore 8.2 initial version. There are no errors in the Sitecore publishing service installation and also during the module installation.

The issue is when we try to publish, the publish dialog doesn't display any languages. I have tried the suggestions mentioned in [Sitecore Publishing Service does not show the languages and seeing 404 errors](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/5958/sitecore-publishing-service-does-not-show-the-languages-and-seeing-404-errors) but still have the same issue with languages.

I do not see any errors in the logs which could indicate an issue during the publish dialog is loaded. Can anyone let me know if you have come across this issue and if this was resolved?

Below is a screenshot of the publish dialog and how it looks.

[image]