# Publishing target missing after installing Sitecore publishing module

Tags: publishing-service

After installing Sitecore publishing module package on my sitecore 9 instance, l can no more see the languages and targets when I try to publish an item. I have installed publishing service as well and see the same behaviour there when I try to publish site. I have checked the configuration and the database and targets are present there. Is it a known issue or am i missing something in configuration. [image]

Comment: This article has all necessary information to set it correctly -> http://blog.alpha-solutions.us/2017/03/sitecore-publishing-service-2-0-how-to-setup-a-publishing-target/

Comment: Had this issue as well. It was a browser issue, so a very quick workaround was to use a different browser.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Peter, there were indeed few settings missing in the publishing service configuration which i corrected from the article you provided, but the issue which i was facing i.e. publishing target not showing up was due to someone unknowingly checking in a patch file for publishing services i.e. publishingservices.config.

The patch file was containing a different url for publishing service and was overriding the one which i provided in the original config.

The config was cached by asp.net and hence was still pointing to the wrong url given in patch file. I am not sure why sitecore didn't show me the error but after cleaning temporary asp.net files sitecore start showing error for wrong publishing url.

On correcting the url, the target start appearing in my publishing dialog box. 
I did IIS reset multiple times but it has no effect and only clearing of temporary asp.net file helped. This is the link which mentioned clearing temporary files [Sitecore Publishing Service does not show the languages and seeing 404 errors](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/5958/sitecore-publishing-service-does-not-show-the-languages-and-seeing-404-errors/5959#5959)